# IEnumerable from IEnumerator

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

I have writen about custom `IEnumerator`. Whats the simplest way to make `IEnumerable` from it ? Ideal solution (one line of code) would be if there was some class for that purpose. Or do I have to create my own ?

Comment: Unfortunately you have to make your own.

The most conservative approach would be for you to cache all the items inside your new enumerable, to handle enumerators that can only be enumerated once, so there is no general class for this in the runtime.

Why, specifically, do you need to do this? Why can't you work with the original enumerable in this setting?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: Performance reasons. I need an `IEnumerable` of all children `DependencyObject` s of some UIElement. To get them I use `VisualTreeHelper` class. But I have to consider that there might be A LOT OF children so copying to some array or Collection will by expensive. – drasto 5 mins ago

Comment: Also - random question... **why** have you hand-writen an `IEnumerator` - why not just an iterator block? which btw can be (automatically) `IEnumerable[<T>]` **or** `IEnumerator[<T>]`. Other than for examples to compare, I haven't written an iterator manually since C# 2.0

Comment: @Marc Gravell: What do you mean by iterator blok ? I don't know that term... Well I'm still new to C#.

Comment: see the **free** chapter 6 here: http://www.manning.com/skeet/ ("Implementing
 iterators the easy way") - but short version: `yield return`. Oh, that is an excellent book by the way... worth buying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would really approach this the other way around; while you *can* (as per Mike P's excellent answer) wrap an enumerator to pretend to be enumerable, there are some things that you can't really do - for example, it is *hoped* (although, to be fair, not insisted) that you can obtain *multiple* enumerators from an enumerable, ideally isolated and repeatable. So if I do:

```
Assert.AreEqual(sequence.Sum(), sequence.Sum());
```

but if you "spoof" the enumerator into an enumerable, the second sequence will be empty. Or if you do them in parallel - just bizarre. And there *are* methods that process them in parallel - consider:

```
Assert.IsTrue(sequence.SequenceEqual(sequence));
```

this works both enumerators forward *at the same time*, so if you only **have** one enumerator, you are fairly scuppered.

There *is* a reset on enumerators, but this is largely a design mistake and shouldn't be used (it is even a formal requirement in the spec that iterator blocks throw an exception if you call it).

A better (IMO) question is "how do I get an enumerator from an enumerable", in which case the answer is "call GetEnumerator(), and remember to check to dispose to iterator" - or in simpler terms "use `foreach`".

Comment: The mistake with "Reset" was with just having one type of enumerable.  IMHO, there should have been an IMultipassEnumerable, inheriting IEnumerable, which would support Reset and guarantee that multiple passes will either return identical data or throw an exception; an ordinary IEnumerable whose collection was modified should be allowed to return 'sensible' data if it's able to do so or throw an exception if it can't, and an ISafeEnumerable, which would be expected to work sensibly (without throwing an exception) even if a collection changes.  A bit late now to change things, though.

Answer (score 21):

There's no built-in method, unfortunately. I have this extension method that I use often enough:

```
static IEnumerable Iterate(this IEnumerator iterator)
{
while (iterator.MoveNext())
    yield return iterator.Current;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In my collection of C# utils I have this:

```
class Enumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    Func<IEnumerator<T>> factory;
    public Enumerable(Func<IEnumerator<T>> factory) { this.factory = factory; }
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() { return this.factory(); }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return this.GetEnumerator(); }
}
```

This takes an **IEnumerator factory function**, which usually can be provided very easily instead of the single IEnumerator instance (which yields wrong results after first iteration and breaks the semantics of IEnumerable). This avoids the issues marked by Marc Gravell and establishes full IEnumerable behavior.

I use it this way:

```
IEnumerable<Fruit> GetFruits()
{
    var arg1 = ...
    return new Enumerable<Fruit>(() => new FruitIterator(arg1, arg2, ...));
}
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple:

```
class Enumerate : IEnumerable
{
    private Enumerate IEnumerator it;
    public Enumerate(IEnumerator it) { this.it = it; }
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() { return this.it; }
}
```

This also allows the user to call `IEnumerator.Reset()` if the enumerator you gave it supports it.

Comment: i also used this and was loooong happy. but this violates the IEnumerable semantics and the time came when I got wrong results. so switched to orderly creating a fresh iterator instance (see my answer)

Comment: @citykid: Yeah, the premise of doing this in the first place is questionable... but if you have to, this is how you do it.

Comment: that's not really valid. IEnumerable::GetEnumerator() must return a new IEnumerator on each call, otherwise one can only once foreach over the enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is make a class that implements both IEnumerator and IEnumerable. Make GetEnumerator() return itself and you can iterate it like normal.

```
public class MyClassEnumerator : IEnumerator<MyClass>, IEnumerable<MyClass>
{
    public MyClass Current { get; private set; }

    object IEnumerator.Current => Current;

    public void Reset()
    {
        ...
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        ...
    }

    public IEnumerator<MyClass> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```